# How to change this \renewcommand\section to prevent page break just after the title?

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

I am using the following command in my class ([thanks to this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148269/3957)):

```
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
                                {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                {-1em}%
                                {\normalfont\large\bfseries}*}
```

Now I had the problem that the section title happened to be the last thing on a page, and its corresponding text ended up in the next page. How to change this definition to prevent this problem to happen? I tried adding a `\nopagebreak` as last thing before `}`, with no success...

Comment: What you ask for is the default behavior of the `\@startsection` command. Also the definition you exhibit for `\section` puts the section title on the same line as the text of the first paragraph, which contradicts your description. So please provide a minimal working example (MWE) document that exhibits this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [titlesec](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/layout/titlesec.pdf) package to redefine the `\section` command. For example, it says:

> If you dislike typing the full skip values, including the plus and
>   minus parameters, an abreviation `*n` is provided (where n is an
>   integer). In the `beforesep` argument this is equivalent to `n ex`
>   with some stretchability and a minute shrinkability. In the `aftersep`
>   some strechability (smaller) and no shrinkability. Thus, you can write

```
\titlespacing*{command}{left}{beforesep}{aftersep}[right]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*4}{*1}
```

**Edit:** The following example I believe successfully keeps the `\section` with the text below it.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % generate filler text
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[runin]
{\large\bfseries}
{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}
{0pt}{*2}{*1}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\lipsum[1-5]

\section{Section 2}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: And how those spacing settings will effect the prevention of page break just after the title?

Comment: See edited post with new example

Comment: I think you misunderstood me (or maybe I was not clear enought) you managed to get the title on the same line of the text; that is not what I wanted. I wanted the title on one line, followed by the text paragraph below it, but should have a way to tell LaTeX the title and the text are semantically related so the title must not end a page so its text will start next. It is like using `~` to prevent the line break algorithm to place two words on separated lines...

Comment: Ah. When I compiled the example using the code which you originally provided in the question, in the output, the text followed the title like the `\paragraph` command.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why exactly it worked, but I managed to do it. I just had to add `\leavevmode` at the beginning of the definition:

```
\renewcommand\section{\leavevmode\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
                                {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                {-1em}%
                                {\normalfont\large\bfseries}*}
```

If you know why it works or whether it as the "right" solution, please tell me!

EDIT: it seems it doesn't affect all cases where a page break could happen, so it is not a complete solution.